# Javascript d3 object string to number

Tags: javascript, d3.js, type-conversion

I have a csv and i am trying to convert certain data to integers when i parse the object it is still showing up in the console as a string.

```
d3.csv('somecsv.csv' function(response){
  var data = response.map(function(item){
    var newItem{};
    newItem[parseInt("Column with spaces 1")] = item["Column with spaces 1"];
// This gives a Nan error
// even when i do 
//   newItem["Column with spaces 1"] = item["Column with spaces 1"];
//   parseInt(newItem["Column with spaces 1"])
   console.log(newItem)
//  This displays a string. It never converted to an Int.
```

When i console.log the data is stored in an object that looks like this

```
Object { "Column with spaces 1": "99", "Column with spaces 2": "37"  }
```

I want to convert it so it the value is a number not string

```
Object { "Column with spaces 1": 99, "Column with spaces 2": 37  }
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the data stored in the csv, and the expected output for that example?

Comment: `newItem["Column with spaces 1"] = parseInt(item["Column with spaces 1"])` and the same for the other property.

Comment: for a more dynamic way: `Object.keys(item).forEach(key => newItem[key] = +item[key])`. It handles all the keys.

Answer (score 1):

It should be enough to convert it to number by adding [unary operator `+`](https://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript-unary-operators-simple-and-useful#toc-unary-plus-) to the value of item, so something like:

```
d3.csv('somecsv.csv', function(data) {
  const cleanData = data.map((d) => ({
     ...d,
     fieldNameWithNumber: +d[fieldNameWithNumber]
  });
});
```